# Somehow, once my cygwin gcc compiler gltiched

Tags: c

I had two calls to the **wcslen** function in my code. When I called them, they returned lengths of wide char strings, but **including** null termination character. I am completely sure there are no outside interferences to these measured wstrings. I changed my compiler from cygwin gcc to mingw gcc in order to not be cygwin dll dependent, it showed normal results by excluding null termation char. When I switched back to the cygwin gcc it was suddenly fixed and my program worked as it was supposed to.

Snippet of my code, where this happened:

```
size_t s = wcslen(directory) + wcslen(fn) + 2;
```

^^^ When I check this variable, it was larger than it's supposed to be by 2 bytes(because of the null term)

```
WCHAR *fullfn = (WCHAR *)calloc(s, sizeof(WCHAR));


wcscat(fullfn, directory); wcscat(fullfn, L"\\"); wcscat(fullfn, fn);
```

So, what could it be? I'm sure it was not a hallucination.

Comment: The `calloc` allocation isn't enough. You allowed for the NUL terminator but not the `L"\\"`. The undefined behaviour from exceeding the memory allocation caused unexpected results. The NUL terminator is never included in the length, but the length is greater than you expected due to the `L"\\"`. The compiler should never be accused - the reason is nearly always in one's own coding.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think the 2 in `wcslen(directory) + wcslen(fn) + 2` is one for the `\\` and one for the NUL.

Comment: @Null: allocating too much space won't stop your program from working. So there is something you're not telling us. Please include that information. Include all details, including how you check the value of `s`, what that value is, and evidence that it is wrong.

Comment: @rici yes, I was distracted by "larger than it's supposed to be by 2 bytes" which should say "2 elements".

Comment: Most commonly when strings are one character longer than expected on windows, the cause is an extra CR (\r) character somewhere.